# Postgresql Database Details

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

First thing first let me give some information about my environment :

1. Ubuntu server 16.04 LTS
2. Postgresql 12 = I installed it on /var/lib/postgresql/12/main

inside /var/lib/postgresql/12/main :

```
drwx------ 10 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 21 17:13 base
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 26 19:29 global
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_commit_ts
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_dynshmem
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 26 19:33 pg_logical
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 26 19:28 pg_notify
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_replslot
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_serial
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_snapshots
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 26 19:28 pg_stat
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_twophase
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    3 Jan  9 16:54 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Feb 17 19:07 pg_wal
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 16:54 pg_xact
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   88 Jan  9 16:54 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  130 Feb 26 19:28 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  101 Feb 26 19:28 postmaster.pid
```

I have a lit bit of confusion when I want to fill the details of the PostgreSQL connection. What to fill in PGBIN ??

```
#!/bin/bash
#Provide your database details here -----
export PGBIN=path_to_psql
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGPORT=5433
export CITYDB=3dcitydb
export PGUSER=postgres
```

Regard,

Yogi

Comment: A connection information does not require a "pgbin" property. And to specify the database in an environment variable you should use `PGDATABASE`

Comment: why port is 5433? It is 5432 by default.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I need to install 3citydb and it requires me to fill that connection_details.

Comment: To specify the database you should use `export PGDATABASE=3dcitydb` all environment variables are documented here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I run 2 different PostgreSQL versions and for this project, I use PostgreSQL v12 that runs on port 5433

Comment: It's asking you for the postgres command line client executable location. Type in `which psql` into your shell and paste the answer (without the `/psql` part) into that first `PGBIN`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just checked parameter for PGBIN and I found nothing.

Comment: that's what I said in my first comment. Where did you get the impression that there is such an option?

Comment: @JNevill okay. I got it on /usr/bin/psql, so it should be /usr/bin. Thank you :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just checked the documentation for 3dCityDB and I found this connection detail (for windows) :                                                
PGBIN= C:\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin
PGHOST=localhost
PGPORT=5432
CITYDB=citydb_v4
PGUSER=citydb_user